# Find highest 3 values in a row and return corresponding column headers in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

In MS Excel, I am trying to identify the highest 3 values within a row and match the relevant corresponding header value. However, when the values are the same it returns the same header value. However, I would like it to return the next header value.

[image]

Comment: what formulas are you using? Does the area of calc change?

Comment: I can't see you pic from here, but try using LARGE() function

Comment: Thanks Krib and iDevelop for replying to my question, Dirk solved it for me using Large and index array formulas.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the label "Largest" to be at `A2` put in cells

```
A3:  =IFERROR(LARGE(G3:M3,1),"")
B3:  =IF(A3="","",INDEX($1:$1,1,LARGE((G3:M3=A3)*COLUMN(G3:M3),1)))
C3:  =IFERROR(LARGE(G3:M3,2),"")
D3:  =IF(C3="","",INDEX($1:$1,1,LARGE((G3:M3=C3)*COLUMN(G3:M3),1+(A3=C3))))
E3:  =IFERROR(LARGE(G3:M3,3),"")
F3:  =IF(E3="","",INDEX($1:$1,1,LARGE((G3:M3=E3)*COLUMN(G3:M3),1+(A3=E3)+(C3=E3))))
```

> Cells `B3`, `D3` and `F3` are array formulas and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Hi Dirk, your array formulas worked a treat, thanks a million for your help, I really appreciate it.